# Roundcube issue : connection to storage server failed

Tags: storage, roundcube

I am getting this error("connection to storage server failed") lines in Roundcube. I have checked everything, configurations, and database user name password, server details all are clean. can anybody tell me what could possibly be the issue? Here I am giving the whole config file.

```
            <?php
        
        $rcmail_config = array();
        $rcmail_config['debug_level'] = 9;
        
        $rcmail_config['log_driver'] = 'file';
        $rcmail_config['log_date_format'] = 'd-M-Y H:i:s O';
        
        $rcmail_config['syslog_id'] = 'roundcube';
        
        $rcmail_config['syslog_facility'] = LOG_USER;
        
        $rcmail_config['smtp_log'] = true;
        
        $rcmail_config['log_logins'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['log_session'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['sql_debug'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['imap_debug'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['ldap_debug'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['smtp_debug'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['default_port'] = 143;
        
        $rcmail_config['imap_auth_type'] = NULL;
        
        $rcmail_config['imap_delimiter'] = NULL;
        
        $rcmail_config['imap_ns_personal'] = NULL;
        $rcmail_config['imap_ns_other'] = NULL;
        $rcmail_config['imap_ns_shared'] = NULL;
        
        $rcmail_config['imap_force_caps'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['imap_force_lsub'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['imap_force_ns'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['imap_timeout'] = 0;
        
        $rcmail_config['imap_auth_cid'] = NULL;
        
        $rcmail_config['imap_auth_pw'] = NULL;
        
        $rcmail_config['imap_cache'] = NULL;
        
        $rcmail_config['messages_cache'] = false;
        
        
        $rcmail_config['smtp_server'] = '';
        $rcmail_config['smtp_port'] = 25;
        $rcmail_config['smtp_user'] = '%u';
        $rcmail_config['smtp_pass'] = '%p';
        
        $rcmail_config['smtp_auth_type'] = '';
        $rcmail_config['smtp_auth_cid'] = NULL;
        $rcmail_config['smtp_auth_pw'] = NULL;
        
        $rcmail_config['smtp_helo_host'] = '';
        
        $rcmail_config['smtp_timeout'] = 0;
        $rcmail_config['enable_installer'] = true;
        
        $rcmail_config['support_url'] = 'http://poolavadi.com/';
        
        $rcmail_config['skin_logo'] = '';
        
        $rcmail_config['auto_create_user'] = true;
        
        $rcmail_config['log_dir'] = 'logs/';
        
        $rcmail_config['temp_dir'] = 'temp/';
        
        $rcmail_config['message_cache_lifetime'] = '10d';
        
        $rcmail_config['force_https'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['use_https'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['login_autocomplete'] = 0;
        
        $rcmail_config['login_lc'] = 0;
        
        $rcmail_config['skin_include_php'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['display_version'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['session_lifetime'] = 10;
        
        $rcmail_config['session_domain'] = '';
        
        $rcmail_config['session_name'] = NULL;
        
        $rcmail_config['session_storage'] = 'db';
        
        $rcmail_config['memcache_hosts'] = NULL; 
        $rcmail_config['ip_check'] = true;
        
        
        $rcmail_config['referer_check'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['x_frame_options'] = 'sameorigin';
        
        $rcmail_config['des_key'] = 'nSfL_Rz6tc5NRMqKpw7d&A9=';
        
        $rcmail_config['username_domain'] = 'poolavadi.com';
        $rcmail_config['mail_domain'] = '';
        
        $rcmail_config['password_charset'] = 'ISO-8859-1';
        
        $rcmail_config['sendmail_delay'] = 0;
        
        $rcmail_config['max_recipients'] = 0; 
        
        $rcmail_config['max_group_members'] = 0; 
        
        $rcmail_config['useragent'] = 'Roundcube Webmail/RCMAIL_VERSION';
        
        $rcmail_config['product_name'] = 'பூளவாடி மின்னஞ்சல்';
        
        $rcmail_config['include_host_config'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['generic_message_footer'] = '';
        
        $rcmail_config['generic_message_footer_html'] = '';
        
        $rcmail_config['http_received_header'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['http_received_header_encrypt'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['mail_header_delimiter'] = NULL;
        
        $rcmail_config['line_length'] = 72;
        
        $rcmail_config['send_format_flowed'] = true;
        
        $rcmail_config['dont_override'] = array();
        
        $rcmail_config['identities_level'] = 0;
        
        $rcmail_config['client_mimetypes'] = NULL;  # null == default
        
        $rcmail_config['mime_magic'] = NULL;
        
        $rcmail_config['im_identify_path'] = NULL;
        
        $rcmail_config['im_convert_path'] = NULL;
        
        $rcmail_config['contact_photo_size'] = 160;
        
        $rcmail_config['email_dns_check'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['plugins'] = array();
        
        $rcmail_config['message_sort_col'] = '';
        
        $rcmail_config['message_sort_order'] = 'DESC';
        
        $rcmail_config['list_cols'] = array('subject', 'status', 'fromto', 'date', 'size', 'flag', 'attachment');
        
        $rcmail_config['language'] = 'en_us';
        
        $rcmail_config['date_format'] = 'Y-m-d';
        
        $rcmail_config['date_formats'] = array('Y-m-d', 'd-m-Y', 'Y/m/d', 'm/d/Y', 'd/m/Y', 'd.m.Y', 'j.n.Y');
        
        $rcmail_config['time_format'] = 'H:i';
        
        $rcmail_config['time_formats'] = array('G:i', 'H:i', 'g:i a', 'h:i A');
        
        $rcmail_config['date_short'] = 'D H:i';
        
        $rcmail_config['date_long'] = 'Y-m-d H:i';
        
        $rcmail_config['drafts_mbox'] = 'Drafts';
        
        $rcmail_config['junk_mbox'] = 'Junk';
        
        $rcmail_config['sent_mbox'] = 'Sent';
        
        $rcmail_config['trash_mbox'] = 'Trash';
        
        $rcmail_config['default_folders'] = array('INBOX', 'Drafts', 'Sent', 'Junk', 'Trash');
        
        $rcmail_config['create_default_folders'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['protect_default_folders'] = true;
        
        $rcmail_config['quota_zero_as_unlimited'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['enable_spellcheck'] = true;
        
        $rcmail_config['spellcheck_dictionary'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['spellcheck_engine'] = 'pspell';
        
        $rcmail_config['spellcheck_uri'] = '';
        
        $rcmail_config['spellcheck_languages'] = NULL;
        
        $rcmail_config['spellcheck_ignore_caps'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['spellcheck_ignore_nums'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['spellcheck_ignore_syms'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['recipients_separator'] = ',';
        
        $rcmail_config['max_pagesize'] = 200;
        
        $rcmail_config['min_keep_alive'] = 60;
        
        $rcmail_config['upload_progress'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['undo_timeout'] = 0;
        $rcmail_config['address_book_type'] = 'sql';
        $rcmail_config['ldap_public'] = array();
        
        $rcmail_config['autocomplete_addressbooks'] = array('sql');
        $rcmail_config['autocomplete_min_length'] = 1;
        
        $rcmail_config['autocomplete_threads'] = 0;
        
        $rcmail_config['autocomplete_max'] = 15;
        
        $rcmail_config['address_template'] = '{street}<br/>{locality} {zipcode}<br/>{country} {region}';
        
        $rcmail_config['addressbook_search_mode'] = 0;
        
        $rcmail_config['default_charset'] = 'ISO-8859-1';
        
        $rcmail_config['skin'] = 'larry';
        
        $rcmail_config['mail_pagesize'] = 50;
        
        $rcmail_config['addressbook_pagesize'] = 50;
        
        $rcmail_config['addressbook_sort_col'] = 'surname';
        
        $rcmail_config['addressbook_name_listing'] = 0;
        
        $rcmail_config['timezone'] = 'auto';
        
        $rcmail_config['prefer_html'] = true;
        
        $rcmail_config['show_images'] = 0;
        
        $rcmail_config['htmleditor'] = 0;
        
        $rcmail_config['prettydate'] = true;
        
        $rcmail_config['draft_autosave'] = 300;
        
        $rcmail_config['preview_pane'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['preview_pane_mark_read'] = 0;
        
        $rcmail_config['logout_purge'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['logout_expunge'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['inline_images'] = true;
        
        $rcmail_config['mime_param_folding'] = 0;
        
        $rcmail_config['skip_deleted'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['read_when_deleted'] = true;
        
        $rcmail_config['flag_for_deletion'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['keep_alive'] = 60;
        
        $rcmail_config['check_all_folders'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['display_next'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['autoexpand_threads'] = 0;
        
        $rcmail_config['top_posting'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['strip_existing_sig'] = true;
        
        $rcmail_config['show_sig'] = 1;
        
        $rcmail_config['sig_above'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['force_7bit'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['search_mods'] = NULL;  
        
        $rcmail_config['addressbook_search_mods'] = NULL;  
        
        $rcmail_config['delete_always'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['delete_junk'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['mdn_requests'] = 0;
        
        $rcmail_config['mdn_default'] = 0;
        
        $rcmail_config['dsn_default'] = 0;
        
        $rcmail_config['reply_same_folder'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['forward_attachment'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['default_addressbook'] = NULL;
        
        $rcmail_config['spellcheck_before_send'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['autocomplete_single'] = false;
        
        $rcmail_config['default_font'] = '';
```

Answer (score 12):

It means dovecot is not running.

run `sudo dovecot`

this was the solution I got after spending hours in frustration

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Also include something about using systemctl status dovecot to check for errors in the dovecot config file

Answer (score 4):

Try turning all the debugging options on and talk to the IMAP server directly without involving RoundCube, see [this guide](http://www.anta.net/misc/telnet-troubleshooting/imap.shtml). That way you can be sure that your IMAP server is working before trying to get RoundCube working.

Answer (score 4):

edit 15-mailboxes.conf by running

```
nano /etc/dovecot/conf.d/15-mailboxes.conf
```

add following text inside namespace inbox {} block:

```
namespace inbox {
    inbox = yes
...
```

save the file and run:

```
service dovecot restart
```

and you are done..!

Answer (score 3):

One possible cause is that your Dovecot installation is not working. This happened to me after changing mysql version. I had to do:

```
sudo apt-get install dovecot-mysql
sudo service dovecot restart
```

Then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this issue by referring to **Dovecot Status**.

First of all, make sure you don't use an incognito browser window, then Check Dovecot Status by running this command

```
service dovecot status
```

it will show you that:

```
    ● dovecot.service - Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dovecot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: **inactive** (dead) since Mon 2020-03-30 21:03:32 UTC; 29min ago
     Docs: man:dovecot(1)
           http://wiki2.dovecot.org/
 Main PID: 910 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Then run `service dovecot start`

Answer (score 1):

Some Devcot config files had been corrupted. So you need to fix by recreate new config file and remove existing one. Login to root by SSH through putty software

Execute these code

```
cd /home
/etc/init.d/dovecot stop
rm -f */imap/*/*/Maildir/dovecot*
rm -f */imap/*/*/Maildir/.*/dovecot*
rm -f */Maildir/dovecot*
rm -f */Maildir/.*/dovecot*
/etc/init.d/dovecot restart
```

Now you can Login into your webmail app. No error will appear.

[Source](http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=473)

Comment: my `/etc/init.d/dovecot` does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when upgrading from Debian Jessie to Stretch. I looked in the log:

```
/var/log/syslog
```

and found that the problem was that I was disabling protocol `SSLv2` explicitly, and it was not supported anymore. I removed it from the list of protocols and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

remove below file and login.

```
/etc/dovecot/conf.d/15-mailboxes.conf
```

or use

```
sudo rm -rf nano /etc/dovecot/conf.d/15-mailboxes.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after migrating to a new server, I thorough check of the config show that my IMAP and IMAPS were disabled, I simply enabled both service and restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you fix it:

Check the log:
**tail /var/log/dovecot.log**

if you see:

> Fatal: Unknown database driver 'mysql'

Meaning missing package! Dovecot requires the dovecot-mysql package to run mysql authentication. This problem is simply cured by installing it with yum:

**yum install dovecot-mysql**

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem recently after successful installation of **roundcube**

first I tried these two command lines:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep :143

telnet localhost 143
```

I got **connection refused** error messages.

so I have to install `telnet`

```
apt-get install telnetd
```

After installation successful then run Restarts

```
/etc/init.d/openbsd-inetd restart

/etc/init.d/dovecot restart
```

Then again run

```
 netstat -tulpn | grep :143
```

Result

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      13439/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN      13439/dovecot
```

Try Second test run

```
telnet localhost 143
```

Result

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
 * OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE START TLS AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN] Dovecot (Ubuntu) ready.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue and I found solution by following.

I had checked log by following command.

```
tail /var/log/dovecot.log
```

By using above command , I found following error in log.

> Sep 01 10:39:50 imap(mail@yourdomain.com): Error: user
>   mail@yourdomain.com: Initialization failed: Initializing mail storage
>   from mail_location setting failed:
>   mkdir(/var/vmail/yourdomain.com/mail) failed: Permission denied
>   (euid=101(vmail) egid=12(mail) missing +w perm: /var/vmail, dir owned
>   by 4325:4319 mode=0751)

so I noticed that server is unable to create the directory with name "yourdomain.com" and it require "+w" permission. I have also noticed that "yourdomain.com" directory requires ownership "vmail:mail".

Finally, Directory had been created using following command .

```
cd /var/vmail/;
mkdir yourdomain.com;
chown vmail:mail yourdomain.com -R;
chmod +w yourdomain.com;
```

That's it.

I hope this answer might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when setting up **iRedMail** dockerized version on **Ubuntu 20.04**.

The issue was that **Dovecot** was not running in the container when I checked using the command - `service dovecot status`. And when I tried starting the service using the command - `service dovecot start` I got the error

```
root@mail:/var/spool/postfix# service dovecot start    
 * Starting IMAP/POP3 mail server dovecot
Error: bind(/var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-auth) failed: No such file or directory
Fatal: Failed to start listeners
```

I also ran the command below to confirm that my dovecot configuration was fine:

```
dovecot -n
```

And yes the output from the command showed that it was fine.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

The issue was caused by **Postfix** not being installed/running on the in my container which I discovered when I checked the docker logs for the container using - `docker logs container-id`. The file `/var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-auth` which **Dovecot** was referencing was supposed to be created by **Postfix**, however, since the script to install **Postfix** failed because the correct path to the script was not picked when building the **iRedMail** image, this issue then came up as **Dovecot** could not find the file `/var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-auth`:

```
[iRedMail] [Entrypoint] /docker/entrypoints/postfix.sh 
/docker/entrypoints/functions.sh: line 113: /docker/entrypoints/postfix.sh: No such file or directory
[iRedMail] [Entrypoint] /docker/entrypoints/mlmmj.sh 
[iRedMail] [Entrypoint] /docker/entrypoints/mlmmjadmin.sh 
[iRedMail] [Entrypoint] /docker/entrypoints/iredapd.sh 
[iRedMail] [Entrypoint] /docker/entrypoints/antispam.sh 
mail: cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status
```

All I had to do was to pull the docker repository for **iRedMail** using `git clone -b stable https://github.com/iredmail/dockerized`, rebuilt the image in my local using `docker build . --tag iredmail:latest -f dockerized/Dockerfiles/Dockerfile`, and then run it. This time the correct location of my **Postfix** install script was picked, and the Postfix installation and setup ran fine.

And when I checked **Dovecot** service again using:

```
service dovecot start
```

It showed me that it was running fine.

**That's all**

Answer (score -4):

You should remove to dovecot mail server and Use another mail services, Two services could be conflitcs therefore You must remove a mail services, I've tried to this error for 2 days.

CODE : yum remove dovecot

If you had used this code Dovecot would have remove from your server and There is not conflitcs